# How to say or suggest in an informal (and possibly rude) way that someone can be disregarded?

Tags: vocabulary, informal, offensive

**Warning**: the English language I would like to know of a Korean equivalent for is rude, and contained in the examples below.

---

> Friend A: *We need to start walking now, or we're going to be late. Where's John?*
>  Friend B: *Aaah, fuck him. He can meet us there.*

From this example, we can understand that B wishes to disregard John's feelings/needs, and is suggesting to A that they leave without him. We might understand friend B to be a little angry with John for being late.

Another common phrase in English is:

> Fuck 'em if they can't take a joke

which means that if someone should be ignored if they don't have a sense of humour.

What construction(s) could be used to express these examples in Korean?

Comment: I notice a flag and a couple of downvotes. I've opened a meta question: http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/questions/137/questions-about-offensive-language-should-they-be-allowed-and-should-we-take. If it's the language that's a problem, I'd welcome suggestions on alternative English examples that *mean the same thing*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could translate the first example as:

Friend A: 우리 지금 출발 안하면 늦을 것 같아. John은 어디있어?

Friend B: 에이.. 좃까. 거기서 보겠지 뭐.

But, If I were Friend B, I'd just say: 에이.. 버려(abandon). 거기서 보겠지 뭐.

The first word has a sexual origin just like "fuck him". But for some reason, I feel the Korean counterpart is more offensive and I only use that among few very old friends.

'disregard' in Korean, "무시" is a simple enough word that any replacement will not have much merit over it.